# In Rust, is it possible to define an object safe trait that requires a constructor function of the implementing type?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a sorting visualisation program and have different structs corresponding to different sorting algorithms. They all implement the `Algorithm` trait (a subtrait of `Ord` and `From<usize>`), which requires an implementation of `fn new() -> Self` and of `fn tick(&mut self, l: &mut List)`. Since the constructor returns a `Self` this trait is not object safe. However, I would like the user to be able to pass in the algorithm they want to see at runtime. I think this should be possible in theory, but I'm struggling to come up with how. I'm not particularly looking forward to constructing vtables manually, but surely this is either a solved problem / definitive "nope, not possible".

I realise that by defifnition, requiring `Self: Sized` opts out of object safety; however I don't see a way around needing to assign `Self::new()` to `*self` in the `reset()` function. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

The full trait definitions looks like the following:

```rust
pub trait ListItem
where
    Self: Ord + Clone + From<usize>,
{
    fn select(&mut self);
    fn deselect(&mut self);
}

pub trait Algorithm
where
    Self::Item: ListItem,
    Self: Sized,
{
    type Item;
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn tick(&mut self, l: &mut List<Self::Item>) -> AlgorithmState; // just an enum
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        *self = Self::new();
    }
    fn name(&self) -> &'static str;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible.

> however I don't see a way around needing to assign `Self::new()` to `*self` in the `reset()` function

Make a practical compromise: require implementors of the trait to implement `reset()` explicitly. They just have to write the three lines you did.

(This doesn't lose you any guarantees of consistency, because they could override it anyway, and because they could write an impure `new()` function that returns a differently-behaving instance each time.)

Then, to get the trait object-safe the *rest* of the way, you can have a `Self: Sized` bound *only* on `new()`. That means that there just is not any `new()` trait function for `dyn Algorithm`, but there is for all `Sized` concrete implementors of the trait.

```rust
pub trait Algorithm
where
    Self::Item: ListItem,
{
    type Item;
    
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
        
    fn tick(&mut self, l: &mut List<Self::Item>) -> AlgorithmState;
    fn reset(&mut self);
    fn name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

// This won't compile if the trait isn't object-safe
fn _prove_object_safety<L: ListItem>(_: &dyn Algorithm<Item = L>) {}

// Unchanged.
pub trait ListItem
where
    Self: Ord + Clone + From<usize>,
{
    fn select(&mut self);
    fn deselect(&mut self);
}

// For testing.
pub struct List<T>(Vec<T>);
pub struct AlgorithmState;
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to have a new method that's callable from a default implementation since the [docs on object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) say all methods must be dispatchable or explicitly non-dispatchable and that includes it must

> - Be a method that does not use `Self` except in the type of the receiver.
> - Have a receiver with one of the following types:
>
>   ```
>   &Self (i.e. &self)
>   &mut Self (i.e &mut self)
>   Box<Self>
>   Rc<Self>
>   Arc<Self>
>   Pin<P> where P is one of the types above
>   ```

and the return type is not the receiver nor do you even have a receiver.

And those rules aren't arbitrary either, you can't return a plain `Self` when you don't know it's size, so `new` can't be dynamically dispatched in that case.

Things that don't stop your trait from being object safe that you could return if your trait was object safe to begin with:

- `Box<dyn Algorithm>`
- `Rc<dyn Algorithm>` (or `Arc`)
- any other `Algorithm` trait object

Of course none of these variants allow you to provide a default impl for `reset` and I don't see an object safe way to provide one.

And by the way `Self: Sized` on the trait disallows trait objects on it's own since a `dyn Trait` does never implement `Sized` so it can never implement such a trait either.

Comment: Okay, that's in line with what I expected, but then I don't get how I could use `dyn Algorithm` at all, since "[t]o use the trait this way, it must be object safe", as per the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.dyn.html).

Comment: With your current implementation you can't.